# Technical name for underlining an erratic part of the currently writing code

Tags: programming-languages, underline

When we write our code through a programming language like C++, JAVA, etc., the software underlines the problematic part of code upon we are writing that. What is the name of this technology?

Comment: I don't know about a better name than [squigglies](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/squiggly#Noun).

Comment: @svick: Yes. Thanks. This is actually what I was looking for. It's better call it "squiggly lines". But what about the general word of this technology? Please note that "Intelisense" was coined by the Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

Intelligent Code Completion.

Under Visual C++, the technology name is Intelisense. Googling about it leads to the wikipedia article about [**Intelligent Code Completion**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_code_completion).

Comment: Code Completion is about completing the code you're writing, not about highlighting errors and other issues in the code.

Comment: @StephaneRolland **Page 76** of book "Beginning Object-Oriented Programming with C#" by _Jack Purdum_ says: "_Intelisense_ is the name Microsoft has given to the part of Visual Studio responsible for checking your statements ...". _Intelisense_ is responsible for both **intelligent code completion** and **syntax checking**. But I'm looking for a general name.

Comment: the wikipedia article about intelligent code completion that I gave the link to you says: Intelligent code completion is a context-aware code completion feature in some programming environments that speeds up the process of coding applications by reducing typos and other common mistakes. Attempts to do this are usually done through auto completion popups when typing, querying parameters of functions, query hints related to **syntax errors**, etc. Intelligent code completion and related tools serve as documentation and disambiguation for variable names, functions and methods using reflection.